# attributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'transform'

Tags: python, transform

Hi we want to show the output of our categories after we finished training the data sets but we encountered an error in our classification tab here is the codes in our classification tab

```
 def on_classify(self):
        data_classify = self.model_entry.get()

        try:
            global outputClassify
                
            model = self.model_entry.get()
            vectorizer = self.vector_entry.get()
            filenameClassify = self.test_entry.get()

            fileClassify = pd.read_csv(filenameClassify, encoding = "latin-1", sep = "\t", error_bad_lines = False, names = ['date','text'])
```

## THIS IS THE ERROR PART

```
        ER_vector = vectorizer.transform(fileClassify['text'].values.astype('U'))


        date = fileClassify['date']
        text = fileClassify['text']
            
        predictions = model.predict(ER_vector)

        outputClassify = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : date, 'Text' : text, 'Class': predictions })

        pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
        pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
        pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1000)
        pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', True)

        classifyOutput.insert('end', outputClassify)
```

Comment: It appears that the expectation here is that `self.vector_entry.get()` will return an object that has a `transform` method, but it actually returns a string. Without more context, I'm not sure how to debug this any further.

Comment: Can you please give some description of what your code is trying to do. Please read the rules of this platform concerning questions.

Comment: So what is your *question*?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `self.vector_entry.get()` ie. `vector_entry.get()` method inside your class is returning `str` type.

That is why the `vectorizer.trasform` is raising error as "str object has no attribute transform".

Comment: is that because I don't have a function in transform() of my variable vectorizer?

Comment: yes somewhat like that. you intended to return some `vectorizer` object which has method `transform()` in it.. but instead you are returning some string object. check the returning statement of that function `vector_entry.get()`